# If $f(z)=e^z$ then $f(A)=?$...

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let A denote the set of all complex numbers lying within the square having vertices $0,1,\pi i,\pi i +1$. let $f(z)=e^z$ then $f(A)=$

(1) $ \{ \omega : 1\leq \omega \le e \}$

(2) $\{\omega : |\omega| \le e \}$

(3) $\{\omega : 1\leq |ω| \le e, 0\leq \arg \omega \le \pi \}$

(4) $\{\omega : 1\leq |ω| \le e, 0\leq \arg \omega \le \frac{\pi}{2} \}$

I am not getting what to use here. The region they mentioned is a rectangle in first quadrant.so can I say $0 \le \arg \omega \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ The given function is entire, so is analytic in the given region. and $f(z)=e^z$ is continuous also, so can I say by maximum modulus principle, the maximum and minimium lies in the boundary of the region. i.e. $e^0< |f(z)| <e^{\pi i+1}=e$, but still little doubtful here.

So option (3) should be correct. am I correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $z=x+iy$ with $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le y\le\pi$, hence option  (3) is correct.

Comment: That doesn't look much like a square

Comment: As a suggestion, forget all those theorems. Set $\omega = e^{z}$, now draw on the $z$ plane region $A$ (especially the borders) and on the $\omega$ plane the corresponding region.

Comment: Another comment: what did you mean by $e^0< |f(z)| <\color{red}{e^{\pi i+1}}=e\,?$